# Spring boot - Deserialize enum by value lookup

Tags: spring-boot, enums, deserialization

I have the following enum:

```
public enum BusinessType {
  C_CORP("C-Corporation"),
  S_CORP("S-Corporation"),
  // more types

  public final String name;

  BusinessType(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

The front end will submit the name property as a string (eg. C-Corporation), how can I get spring boot to deserialize / look up the correct enum? Currenty it tries to look up the actual string on the enum, giving the error:

```
No enum constant ai.interval.common.model.enums.BusinessType.C-Corporation
```

This is the property I have in the view received from the front end:

```
BusinessType getBusinessType();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Build a getter for your fields, then add the @JsonValue annotation to your getter.

```
public enum BusinessType {
...

@JsonValue
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

}

You can find other options in section 4 of this link: [How To Serialize and Deserialize Enums with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums)